# HQL select error

Tags: hibernate, hql

The code is

```
 String myQuery = "select c.orderId from com.model.Supplier su join com.model.Supplier su2  join su2.product P where su.product.OrderId = :Order and c.order != :Order ";
List<Order> myOrder= getCurrentSession().createQuery(myQuery.toString()).setParameter("Order", aOrder).list();
```

When the above line is executed, I get an error on the screen as

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getLhs(DotNode.java:631)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3671)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3452)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your mappings are right along with foreign keys and such, I think you need to specify the joins like 'left join'.

See valid joins in the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).